# How to make SFF.SE bot to auto-post questions in my chat room?

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

SFF.SE bot automatically posts all new questions to primary chat room. Let's say, I created a chat room for Doctor Who fans and I want all new questions tagged with *doctor-who* in my new chat room. How to do this? Is this even possible? If it's not possible, please consider adding the feature.